# Reputation from two edits is summed up as "2 votes"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page

I guess this is not really the intended behavior:

[image]

Comment: Why not? If have two edit votes on the same post, the display looks reasonable.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that there are edit votes, it reads like th two edits (+2 each) are summed up in +4 as "2 votes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Your comment says](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1875/reputation-from-two-edits-is-summed-up-as-2-votes#comment-2543)

> Oh, I did not know that there are edit votes, it reads like th two edits (+2 each) are summed up in +4 as "2 votes".

– well, but that's exactly what it is. You [suggested *two* edits to that question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/65653/revisions); each of those was approved, and thus you get two +2 each.